# How to do Conact form 7 name field validation?

Tags: plugins, validation, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using **contact-form-7** plugin, where i have created `name` field as Name.

The `name` field is accepting text and number too. But my requirement is that `name` field should not start from number so how i can do the name field only accept text not number ?

```
[text* your-name placeholder "Full Name"]
```

I search on Google and visited contact form 7 support too, but can not solve it.

Comment: Did you read the [developer handbook on custom validation](https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/) already? Also, if my name is something like "kero the 3rd" I won't be able to send your form (because there is a number in it)?

Comment: my requirement is, Name field should not accept name that start with number, not in middle or after first.. @kero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://contactform7.com/2015/03/28/custom-validation/) you have to create a custom filter to support it - you can do it like this:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_text_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function custom_text_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( 'your-name' == $tag->name ) {
        // matches any utf words with the first not starting with a number
        $re = '/^[^\p{N}][\p{L}]*/i';

        if (!preg_match($re, $_POST['your-name'], $matches)) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, "This is not a valid name!" );
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```